# Vector{AbstractString} function parameter won't accept Vector{String} input in julia

Tags: julia, invariance

The following code in Julia:

```
function foo(a::Vector{AbstractString})  
end
foo(["a"])
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Array{String,1})
Closest candidates are:
  foo(::Array{AbstractString,1}) at REPL[77]:2
```

Even though the following code runs, as expected:

```
function foo(a::Vector{String})  
end
foo(["a"])
```

And further, `AbstractString` generally matches `String` as in:

```
function foo(::AbstractString)  
end
foo("a")
```

How can I call a function with a `Vector{AbstractString}` parameter if I have `String` elements?

Answer (score 11):

You need to write the function signature like this:

```
function foo{S<:AbstractString}(a::Vector{S})
    # do stuff
end
```

On Julia 0.6 and newer, it's also possible to write instead

```
function foo(a::Vector{<:AbstractString})
    # do stuff
end
```

This is a consequence of parametric type invariance in Julia. See the [chapter on types](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/?highlight=invariance#man-parametric-types) in the manual for more details.