# Underspecification when checking complex types in Julia

Tags: dictionary, types, tuples, julia, typechecking

Given some complex object, e.g.:

```
> d = Dict(("a", "b")=>3, ("c", "d")=>2)
Dict{Tuple{String,String},Int64} with 2 entries:
  ("c","d") => 2
  ("a","b") => 3
```

I could check the type with:

```
> isa(d, Dict{Tuple{String, String},Int64})
true
```

But when I underspecify the Tuple type, it failed the check:

```
> isa(d, Dict{Tuple,Int64})
false
```

**Is it possible to check for underspecified types in Julia? If so, how? If not, why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia, dictionaries, like arrays, are invariant. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465838/vectorabstractstring-function-parameter-wont-accept-vectorstring-input-in-j) on the concept as it applies to arrays.

This means that:

```
julia> Int <: Number
true
```

but,

```
julia> Vector{Int} <: Vector{Number}
false
```

and similarly,

```
julia> Dict{Int, String} <: Dict{Number, String}
false
```

However, note that `Dict` on its own is abstract, so

```
julia> Dict{Int, String} <: Dict
true
```

and in the code you provide,

```
julia> isa(d, Dict)
true
```

As far as I know, if you want to reason specifically about the pair of types in your dictionary, you will need to reference them explicitly. You can do this using `keytype(d)` and `valtype(d)`. For example, from your question, note that

```
julia> keytype(d) <: Tuple
true
```

Of course, if your dictionary is passed into a function, then you can use `Dict{T1, T2}` in the function signature, and then just reason about `T1` and `T2`...

EDIT: See @FengyangWang's answer for a neat little syntax shortcut being introduced in v0.6

Answer (score 1):

In Julia 0.6 you can simply do

```
isa(d, Dict{<:Tuple, Int64})
```

which means a `Dict` with key type a subtype of `Tuple`, and value type `Int64`.

Note that `Dict{Tuple, Int64}` is **not** an "underspecified" type: it is a concrete type and can have instances. However, `Dict{Tuple{String, String}, Int64}` is not the same thing. The former is a type that accepts all tuples as keys, whereas the latter only accepts `Tuple{String, String}`. This is an example of parametric invariance.