# Why Array{Float64,1} is not a subtype of Array{Real,1} in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to write a Julia function, which can accept both 1-dimensional Int64 and Float64 array as input argument. How can I do this without defining two versions, one for Int64 and another for Float64?

I have tried using Array{Real,1} as input argument type. However, since Array{Int64,1} is not a subtype of Array{Real,1}, this cannot work.

Comment: Have you tried `Array{<:Real,1}`?

Comment: I've tried, it works. thanks so much. But I am curious why this works? what's the difference between them?

Comment: `<:Real` specifies that it’s an array containing a subtype of `Real`, i.e., Julia treats it as a parametric type, if that makes sense...

Comment: See https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1 for more information and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Formal_definition for definitions of invariance and covariance.

Comment: Are you most interested in how to work with this design or why the design is like that in the first place?

Comment: This is kinda-sorta a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465838/vectorabstractstring-function-parameter-wont-accept-vectorstring-input-in-j but that answer doesn't cover the "why"

Answer (score -1):

A genuine, non secure way to do it is, with an example:

```
function square(x)
# The point is for element-wise operation
       out = x.*x
end
```

Output:

```
julia> square(2)
4

julia> square([2 2 2])
1×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  4  4
```